# É possivel usar o terminal externo ao executar um programa Java através do Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

O que eu quero dizer é, consigo trocar para que o output do Netbeans saia no bash do Linux ou no cmd do Windows ao invés de usar o console interno da aplicação do Netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não só é possível como é super fácil, desde que você esteja com suas variáveis de ambiente (`path`) bem configuradas. Além disso, para aplicações menores eu considero até mais fácil (só tenho problemas para gerar o `.jar`[risos]).

Classe de exemplo:

```
public class MinhaClasse{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello, world");
    }
}
```

No CMD:

```
c\> javac MinhaClasse.java
c\> java MinhaClasse.class
Hello, world
```

No terminal:

```
user@Desktop:~$ javac MinhaClasse.java
user@Desktop:~$ java MinhaClasse.class
Hello, world
```

Comment: E para aplicações maiores? com várias classes e uso de JPA/Hibernate,  seria viável usar linha de comando? uma aplicação pra mapear os objects e mostrar o output do log no terminal

Comment: boa pergunta, Lucas
Na verdade, não, nesses casos é melhor usar a IDE

Comment: Pense o seguinte: quanto maior o programa, maior a complexidade, e maior a dificuldade de manter todos os arquivos sincronizados. Mesmo em programas em C/C++, onde se tem o costume de utilizar um editor de texto e o terminal, a IDE começa a se mostrar vantajosa a partir de certa complexidade.

Comment: Na minha opinião, a maior facilidade da IDE em Java é de já separar os fontes das classes, e de exportar tudo para um `.jar` automaticamente (mais uma questão de praticidade). Mas existem pessoas que não dispensam a combinação **terminal + editor de texto**, e, pra esses, ferramentas como o editor Atom, o Sublime Text ou o Vi/Vim possuem centenas de plugins que tornam o desenvolvimento mais prático e simples

Comment: Entendi, vou procurar mais sobre esses editores. Caso recomende algo (em especial algum plugin para o VIM), serei grato, obrigado

Comment: Cara, eu te recomendaria o Atom, porque ele tem um banco de plugins integrado, o que torna bem fácil de usar, e conexão direta com sistemas Git. Do Vim, não conheço muito (não sou um grande fã, acho difícil de usar).

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que sua classe seja uma classe executável, tenha um método main, navegue pelo terminal até o diretório que sua classe se encontra, então digite:

// comando para compilar

> javac SuaClasse.java

// Comando para executar

> java SuaClasse

Exemplo:

```
    public class SuaClasse { 
        public static void main(String[] args){ 
           System.out.println("Hello World Pelo Terminal =D"); 
        } 
     }
```

Usando o terminal:

```
    mac@pc:~$ javac SuaClasse.java
    mac@pc:~$ java SuaClasse
    Hello World Pelo Terminal =D
```